# sudo access to install confluent / kafka platform

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Looking into Confluent Docs for installation, installation commands seems to need sudo permission. I have couple of questions regarding the same:

1. Is it sudo root privileges that are needed here, or should we be sudo'ing to some specific confluent user like cp-kafka to install the platform? I presume we need sudo root privileges for install.
2. Will the platform create all the necessary service user accounts for each of the individual components like Kafka, ZooKeeper etc? Or should they be created upfront and kept ready before installation is initiated?
3. What should be the user group that confluent needs / creates?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include links to the specific docs that you're referencing please?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt here is the link I am referring from Confluent Docs - https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html#systemd-rhel-centos-install As can be seen, all the commands seem to run with elevated privileges. My assumption is that its `sudo root` thats needed here. Also, can you please comment on my other questions as well please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> should we be sudo'ing to some specific confluent user like cp-kafka to install the platform?

So, to clarify, "sudo to a user" is not a phrase in Linux. `su` is the command to "switch users". If you do not currently have `sudo` privileges, then you will need to actually logout and log back in to this other user. This could be done with `su` from that current account, though (which you will be prompted for a password), but not `sudo su`

Those users do not exist prior to installation, and installing any software typically is just `sudo yum install`, for example, assuming your *current user* has access to do so (via `/etc/sudoers`).

> Will the platform create all the necessary service user accounts for each of the individual components like Kafka, ZooKeeper etc?

It should, yes. Maybe except a Zookeeper service user, if I recall correctly because Zookeeper is "installed" within the Kafka directory, owned by `cp-kafka`.

> What should be the user group that confluent needs / creates?

Nothing needs pre-created. The scripts will create `cp-kafka`, `cp-schema-registry`, `cp-kafka-connect`, `cp-ksql`, etc for each component.

---

For easily installing on a cluster, it is recommended to try the [Ansible playbooks](https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/cp-ansible/docs/index.html)

Comment: let me explain my scenario better. In our case, we have a service user account `kfkusr` which we intend to use for all installation process. However, our org practice is not provide root access to any user accounts on the machines unless required. As I am not allowed to login to the machines as root, I have asked for sudo privileges for `kfkusr` account so that I can do Kafka setup using this account.

Comment: Am I correct in saying this statement - **without sudo permissions to `kfkusr` account, we cannot install confluent platform?** - The reason I am saying that statement is because when I look into `/etc/kafka` where a bunch of .properties files are present. As per the Confluent Docs, these files need to be modified. However, these files are owned by `root:root` with permission bits set to 644. So I presume we  need sudo privileges for `kfkusr` to complete the installation, configuration and starting services.

Comment: Followup question - should the `kfkusr` require sudo permission forever or can it be revoked after the services are started? What is the recommended practice? Should the `kfkusr` be made of any specific group so that service installation, configuration and maintenance becomes easier to manage?

Comment: It's not clear how those files got there, but I vaguely recall that all those files are `chown`-ed to the `cp-*` user accounts... I would need to re-install to verify. But yes, to install any software, you need elevated user permissions, and I don't think there is a specific unix group for software installation, so therefore sudoers is it. And with `644`, any user can **read** the property file, so the server can "start". The problem may come from writing to the data directories for any user but root. But still, you can freely `chmod` and `chown` on your own (using sudo as well)